# How do I get the full path of a document open in Windows notepad?

Tags: windows-7, windows, notepad

Is it possible to display the full path of a document opened in Windows notepad in the title or the status bar?

If this is not possible, is there a way to get the full path of a document currently opened in notepad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full path in title bar: Not that I've ever seen.

Full path of file: Closest you'd get would be to "Save As" and see where it puts you.

Notpad is an EXTREMELY simple tool. For these kinds of features you need something more robust, like notepad++, or notepad2, or SublimeText, etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

If the file has unsaved changes, and you click to close it, you get a message containing the full path, e.g. on Notepad (Windows 7): 'Do you want to save changes to C:\New Text Document.txt?'. You can then press ctrl+c to copy the path to the clipboard.

For a file with no unsaved changes one could, for example, press space and then click to close it.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad does not offer this.

My recommendation would be to use an alternative program, such as Notepad++. You can even associate .txt files with these programs, and they offer enough flexibility yet are lightweight so they work as good replacements for notepad.